# Records groupping/counting with zero counts

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with services containing columns ACT_MONTH (activation month) and S_TYPE (service type). I need SQL query that will return a table showing ALL MONTHS and ALL TYPE table combinations with corresponding number of services activated in that month. The problem is when there's no service in some month/type but I need them in this table as zeros. Simple GROUP BY does not show these zero groups.

So the resulting table should look like:

```
ACT_MONTH | S_TYPE | QTY
==========+========+=====
2022M01   | A      |  20
2022M01   | B      |  33
2022M02   | A      |   6
2022M02   | B      |   0
2022M03   | A      |  12
2022M03   | B      |   4
2022M04   | A      |   0
2022M04   | B      |   0
2022M05   | A      |   0
2022M05   | B      |   0
...
2022M12   | A      |   0
2022M12   | B      |   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a calendar and then use a `PARTITION`ed join, partitioning by `s_type`, to make sure there is a combination for each month and `s_type`:

```sql
WITH calendar (month) AS (
  SELECT TO_CHAR(
           ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2022-01-01', LEVEL - 1),
           'YYYY"M"MM'
         ) AS month
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
)
SELECT c.month AS act_month,
       t.s_type,
       COUNT(t.act_month) AS qty
FROM   calendar c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
       PARTITION BY (t.s_type)
       ON (c.month = t.act_month)
GROUP BY
       c.month,
       t.s_type
ORDER BY
       c.month,
       t.s_type;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (act_month, s_type) AS
SELECT '2022M01', 'A' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20 UNION ALL
SELECT '2022M01', 'B' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 33 UNION ALL
SELECT '2022M02', 'A' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  6 UNION ALL
SELECT '2022M03', 'A' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12 UNION ALL
SELECT '2022M03', 'B' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  4;
```

Outputs:

> | ACT_MONTH | S_TYPE | QTY |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022M01 | A | 20 |
> | 2022M01 | B | 33 |
> | 2022M02 | A | 6 |
> | 2022M02 | B | 0 |
> | 2022M03 | A | 12 |
> | 2022M03 | B | 4 |
> | 2022M04 | A | 0 |
> | 2022M04 | B | 0 |
> | ... | ... | ... |
> | 2022M12 | A | 0 |
> | 2022M12 | B | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a0dc0a456d6044c1e337deb9af0df068)*

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN with PARTITION BY (I've never used it myself) resolves my Q, thanks. My solution bellow makes CROSS JOIN table of months and service types and then sums services according to month and service_type but your solution seems to me more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found myself some solution:

```
SELECT
  m,
  s,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM services_table WHERE s_type=s AND act_month=m) qty
FROM
(
  SELECT m,s
  FROM
  (
    SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YEAR'),LEVEL-1),'YYYY"M"MM') AS m
    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
  )
  CROSS JOIN 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT s_type s FROM services_table
  )
)
ORDER BY 1,2
```